# How to call a method in swift for a structure with a new object?

Tags: swift, methods, struct

I created a Phone struct in swift and initialized it. After initializing it I made a method called `chargePhone` which checks if the phone is less than 90 battery and charge it by 10 if it isn't. When I tried using the method for a object i created i ran into an error and I'm not sure how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: Don't post screen shots. Post your code !!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to access `aPhone`  in the same scope as where it is defined

But there are other problems.

First `aPhone`'s type isn't `Phone` so you can't access `aPhone.chargePhone` even if they are in different scope

Second , If you want to access `aPhone.chargePhone` , aPhone must be like

```
let aPhone = Phone(b:75 , c : "Blue"....)
```

even if you will get error.
Structures are value type so you can't make such a definition in struct . You must change it with `class`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was able to fix the errors but for some reason when i print aPhone.battery it doesn't print the new value of 85 which is show in the console on the right side. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYJTa.png

Comment: @ali9000 You have a few mistakes that are related to a misunderstanding of how structs work in Swift (ie copy on write). `chargePhone` should be a `mutating` function. Read up on "copy on write" and "mutating" in Swift.